# Фильтрация списка ArrayList по значению поля объекта списка (Android java)

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как реализовать фильтрацию. Есть список ArrayList notes с двумя полями string, int.
Объекты отображаются в RecyclerView. Так же установлен Spinner. Задача сделать так, чтобы объекты отображались в зависимости от выбранной позиции в спиннере.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно понимать, что сортировать должен себя не сам RecyclerView. Он вообще ничего нет должен знать от сортировке. Вы можете создать в вашем RecyclerView метод вроде такого:

```
public void update(List <YourItem> items){
    this.items.clear();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged ();
}
```

По нажатию на ваш спиннер вы просто сортируете ваш список снаружи и вызываете этот метод с уже сортированным вами списком.

Чтоб отсортировать список по нужному вам полю вам необходимо реализовать свой Comparator. [Здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1939-comparator-v-java) есть неплохой пример.

Так же для того чтоб всякий раз нет обновлять весь список, а перемешать (и с красивой анимацией) только изменившиеся элементы, я рекомендую вам реализовать DiffUtils callback. [Здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html) есть неплохой пример.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то у вас список состоящий из объектов класса, а не например простые данные типа стринг например. Фильтрация в таких массивах делается следующим образом. Допустим есть список:

```
ArrayList<Notes> someList = new ArrayList<Notes>()
```

дальше после этого фильтруем список по id и например нам нужен отфильтрованный список с `id>10`:

```
someList.filter{it.id>10}
```

в строке выше `it` это объект `Notes` с двумя полями `int` и `string`. Я допускаю что поле `int` это какой-то идентификатор. Давайте рассмотрим другой пример - нам нужны записи длина строки которых `==5`:

```
someList.filter{it.text.length() == 5}
```

либо если у вас спиннер, то допускаю что там есть поиск по заметке или что-то типа такого:

```
someList.filter{it.text == "some note text"}
```

Более простой вариант - делать все через цикл. Делаем итоговый список:

```
ArrayList<Notes> resList = new ArrayList<Notes>()
```

и дальше в цикле проходимся по всем элементам исходного списка:

```
for (Notes note : someList) {
    if (note.id > 30) {
        resList.add(note);
    }
}
```

ну и дальше уже как сказал [@SergeiBuvaka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288062/sergei-buvaka) обнвляете ваш виджет.

P.S. @SergeiBuvaka - вы меня немного опередили :)

Answer (score -1):

Сделал костыльный фильтр, через объявление второго листа, которому присвоиваю значения от выбранной позиции в спинере и далее уже этот новый список устанавливаю в адаптер. Вроде работает, но не пойму как реализовать, чтобы каждый раз при выборе позиции в спиннере recyclerViewNotes обновлялся, а не добавлял данные с список. Непойму куда и как запихнуть notifyDataSetChanged();

```
spinnerTaskList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Позиция " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        for (Note note : notes) {
                            if (note.getStatus() == 0) {
                                notesResult.add(note);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        for (Note note : notes) {
                            if (note.getStatus() == 1) {
                                notesResult.add(note);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (Note note : notes) {
                            if (note.getStatus() == 2) {
                                notesResult.add(note);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(notesResult);
                recyclerViewNotes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
                recyclerViewNotes.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){

        }

    });
```

Comment: Очень плохой подход при каждом клике создавать новый адаптер... Я же вам описал вверху решение.

Comment: И там есть второе решение корректное.